# Class not found Exception in Apache camel-spring-security Integration

Tags: spring-security, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I am trying t integrate apache camel with spring security. I am following the documentation http://camel.apache.org/spring-security.html . I have used spring DSL mode for routing configuration.
 Following is my incomplete routing configuration with imported commonDecurity.xml.

**camel.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:spring-security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring-security http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring-security/camel-spring-security.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- import the spring security configuration  -->
    <import resource="classpath:org/apache/camel/component/spring/security/commonSecurity.xml"/>

    <camelContext id="myCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="direct:start"/>
            <!-- The exchange should be authenticated with the role of ADMIN before it is send to mock:endpoint -->
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

**commonSecurity.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:spring-security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
      <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
      </constructor-arg>
      <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <spring-security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <spring-security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </spring-security:authentication-manager>

    <spring-security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
        <spring-security:user name="jim" password="jimspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <spring-security:user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
    </spring-security:user-service>

</beans>
```

However, when I deploy the bundle in servicemix it throws following ClassNotFoundException.

> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-2"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [org.springframework.security.vote.AffirmativeBased] for
>   bean with name 'accessDecisionManager' defined in OSGi
>   resource[classpath:spring-security/commonSecurity.xml|bnd.id=337|bnd.sym=com.genix.casegenix.esb];
>   nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.security.vote.AffirmativeBased not found from
>   bundle [com.genix.casegenix.esb]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1347)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:913)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.security.vote.AffirmativeBased not found from
>   bundle [com.genix.casegenix.esb]  at
>   org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:156)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:265)  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:419)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1270)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.security.vote.AffirmativeBased not found by
>   com.genix.casegenix.esb [337]     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1925)     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:99)
>     ... 17 more

I have already installed following features.

- spring-security/3.1.4
- camel-spring-security/2.16.3

I am using

- sevicemix-7.0.0.M2
- apache-camel-2.16.3

Any kind help appreciated. Thanks

I get following ClassNotFoundException when I try with https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-spring-security example.

> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-2"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting
>   bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class
>   [org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager]
>   for bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in null; nested
>   exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager
>   not found from bundle [com.xxxx.yyyyy.esb]

Comment: Try to look at this example which has updated code: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-spring-security

Comment: @ClausIbsen   I tried with mentioned example. But I still get a ClassNotFoundException. I will update my question with that. Do you think I have missed any feature.